# Multiple Ggplot Graphs (grid.arrange)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a variety of ggplot graphs I would like to mesh together like this:

[image: ggplot_graph1]

In particular, I'm interested in creating the grey textboxes on the top and right hand side of the graph. I've tried using grid.arrange to do this with the following code:

```
yleft <- textGrob("IP/Input (log2)", rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 25))
bottom <- textGrob("IP/Input (log2)", gp = gpar(fontsize = 25))

grid.arrange(XL1_above_gel_plot, plot_1_gel_rep, XL1_plot_log1, XL1_vs_XL2_nogel_log1,plot_1_gel_rep, XL2_above_gel_plot, XL2_vs_XL1_nogel_log1, XL2_plot_log1, ncol=4, nrow=2, top=textGrob("XL1 Gel vs No Gel", gp=gpar(fontsize=25,font=8)), left=yleft, bottom=bottom)
```

I realize without seeing the data it can be hard to recreate this; however, I'm looking more for a general solution that would change the graph I have currently (below) into something like the graph above.

[image: ggplot_graph2]

Answer (score 0):

The text looks like it has been made with [facets](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).

You may want to try something like:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + 
     geom_point() + 
     facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))
```

Which splits the rows and columns of the grid according to the `cyl` and `drv` columns in in the `mpg` data frame.